# How to get purchase date from woocommerce order?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a product loop in Woocommerce.  If a customer has purchased a product before, I would like to replace the purchase product button with a message and the date of the order.  For example.

"You purchased this product on Jan. 15, 2016"

I can get the product id and I can get the current user id, but can't figure out how to use those pieces of info to pull order ids.

```
$postid = get_the_ID();
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$has_product = wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product->id);
```

Ideas?

Comment: please paste your code.

Comment: Could you please explain which page you have to display this new button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function below

```
function _cmk_check_ordered_product( $id ) {
    // Get All order of current user
    $orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
        'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() )
    ) );

    if ( !$orders ) return false; // return if no order found

    $all_ordered_product = array(); // store products ordered in an array

    foreach ( $orders as $order => $data ) { // Loop through each order
        $order_data = new WC_Order( $data->ID ); // create new object for each order
        foreach ( $order_data->get_items() as $key => $item ) {  // loop through each order item
            // store in array with product ID as key and order date a value
            $all_ordered_product[ $item['product_id'] ] = $data->post_date; 
        }
    }
    if ( isset( $all_ordered_product[ $id ] ) ) { // check if defined ID is found in array
        return 'You purchased this product on '. date('M. d, Y', strtotime( $all_ordered_product[ $id ] ) );
    } else {
        return 'Product Never Purchased';
    }
}
```

e.g.
Showing message on single product page `echo _cmk_check_ordered_product( get_the_ID() );`

Comment: Worked well. Thank you.